Getting goodbye error in Ubuntu 22.04 version
When I'm trying install App image in Ubuntu 22.04 version getting fatal415 GPU process isn't usable goodbye error please give me solution for this

What does install app image mean? What are the exact steps you are doing? Your title says Ubuntu 22 there is no such version and you have tagged 22.04 which is correct?

Try running the AppImage with the --disable-gpu-sandbox flag:
./YourAppImage.AppImage --disable-gpu-sandbox

If it doesn't work, you can also try the --ignore-gpu-blacklist flag
